# How to control UITableView cell separator insets and layout margins independently (iOS8 & iOS9)

Tags: ios

This has been a huge topic and source of confusion. All the solutions I found rely on controlling layoutMargins. This is essentially a hack and I'm trying to get to the bottom of it. Layout margins themselves are very useful for controlling the cell content based on screen size. Tight margins look good on iPhone 5 and really bad on iPhone 6+. I want full control over separator insets and layout margins inside each cell. I'm compiling for iOS8 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

(After much investigation here's what I've found)

To fully control both separator insets and layout margins on each cell. You only need this code in your tableview delegate. Nothing else is required on iOS8 or iOS9.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

The cell object controls the separator, and the contentView controls everything else. If your separator inset spaces are showing up in an unexpected color this should solve it:

```
cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor
```